# Go - Interface containing slice wont compile

Tags: go

```
type MyType interface {
    MyStringSlice []string
}
```

What is wrong with this?

It works well as a struct as in:

```
type MyType struct {
    MyStringSlice []string
}
```

but compiles with the following error when set as interface:

```
syntax error: unexpected [, expecting (
```

Comment: What would you expect it to do?

Comment: compile. Im trying to set up an interface that will contain 2 methods and 1 property.  This is the property.

Comment: Unless, interfaces in go cant have properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interface can only hold methods or other interfaces. Have a look at the [Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

Comment: ok that makes sense for the error then.  But it is apparantly not idiomatic to use getters in go.  So how would we have an interface with a property

Comment: It is pretty common to have getters (also in interfaces). The `Error() string` method in the `error` type is an example.

The idiomatic approach is usually to omit the "Get" part in the getter. So `GetStringSlice` would become `StringSlice() []string` in your example. [http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters)